Geometry Application for System of Linear Equations
Question : Find the intersection (if any) of the line $x=(1,0,-1)+\lambda(3,2,1)$ and the plane
$x = (-1,-7,-7) + \alpha(3,5,1)+ \beta(1,-2,-5)$.
My work so far:
I equated both equations and rearranged them as following:
$$\lambda(3,2,1)- \alpha(3,5,1)- \beta(1,-2,-5) = (2,7,6).$$
From here, I obtained $3$ equations with $3$ unknowns:
$$\begin{align}
3\lambda-3\alpha-\beta &= 2\quad\quad(1) \\
2 \lambda - 5 \alpha + 2 \beta &= 7    \quad \quad(2) \\
\lambda - \alpha + 5 \beta &= 6     \quad  \quad(3)
\end{align}$$
Solving this system of equations is my next work.
Assistance with Row-Echelon Reduction and Gaussian Elimination from here would be much appreciated. Thanks.

I cannot see it is a wrong way.  Just proceed.

There is an error in the second equation. It should be $+2\beta$, not $-2\beta$.

W/O = working out. Apologies for the typo, my working out on paper had +2 in it.

You can accept which-ever answer you want to learn more , but did you not specifically want Gaussian Elimination & Row-Echelon Reduction ?

I requested for the Gaussian Elimination & Row-Echelon Reduction methods as that is what my university suggested to use for this question. But the methods provided here made sense as well.

Cramer’s rule is the most convenient way to solve the systems $3\times3$, in my opinion. We have
$$\Delta=\begin{vmatrix}
3 & -3 & -1 \\
2 & -5 & 2 \\
1 & -1 & 5 \\
\end{vmatrix}=-48.$$
$$\Delta_{\lambda}=\begin{vmatrix}
2 & -3 & -1 \\
7 & -5 & 2 \\
6 & -1 & 5 \\
\end{vmatrix}=0.$$
$$\Delta_{\alpha}=\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 2 & -1 \\
2 & 7 & 2 \\
1 & 6 & 5 \\
\end{vmatrix}=48.$$
$$\Delta_{\beta}=\begin{vmatrix}
3 & -3 & 2 \\
2 & -5 & 7 \\
1 & -1 & 6 \\
\end{vmatrix}=-48.$$
Then $$\lambda=\frac{\Delta_{\lambda}}{\Delta}=0,\quad \alpha=\frac{\Delta_{\alpha}}{\Delta}=-1, \quad\beta=\frac{\Delta_{\beta}}{\Delta}=1.$$
The point of intersection is $(1,0,-1)$.

At early learning , you should write out the "Details" with more "Precision" , which will make you avoid mistakes.
It is odd to write that $x$ is a Line & a Plane :
Line $x=(1,0,-1)+\lambda(3,2,1)$
Plane $x = (-1,-7,-7) + \alpha(3,5,1)+ \beta(1,-2,-5)$
Instead try this or some other alternative :
Line $L(x,y,z) \equiv (1,0,-1)+\lambda(3,2,1)$
Plane $P(x,y,z) \equiv (-1,-7,-7) + \alpha(3,5,1)+ \beta(1,-2,-5)$
Now there is some Point where Intersection occurs , hence the $(x,y,z)$ values are matching , hence we get :
$1+3\lambda=-1+3\alpha+1\beta$
$0+2\lambda=-7+5\alpha-2\beta$
$-1+1\lambda=-7+1\alpha-5\beta$
We can arrange that like this :
$+3\lambda-3\alpha-1\beta=-2 \tag{A}$
$+2\lambda-5\alpha+2\beta=-7 \tag{B}$
$+1\lambda-1\alpha+5\beta=-6 \tag{C}$
Already we see that there is some error with your Equations (1) (2) (3).
Moving on , we can try to solve Equations (A) (B) (C) in various ways.
OP : Assistance with Row-Echelon Reduction and Gaussian Elimination from here would be much appreciated thanks.
Subtract 2 times (C) from (B) to get :
$0\lambda-3\alpha-8\beta=+5 \tag{D}$
Subtract 3 times (C) from (A) to get :
$+0\lambda+0\alpha-16\beta=+16 \tag{E}$
Hence , we have $\beta=-1$
Plug into (D) to get $-3\alpha=+5-8$
Hence , we have $\alpha=1$
Plug into (A) to get $+3\lambda-3+1=-2$
Hence , we have $\lambda=0$
It is now easy to get the $(x,y,z)$ values Eg using Line $L$ to get $(1,0,-1)$ at the Point of Intersection.
